# CS1061 on DataRow.Item[string] in .NET4.6

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, datarow

I am just wondering how I got CS1061 compiler error on my code, which includes an MSAccess database connection.
I have the following lines:

```
class Test{
    private CheckersDataSet.UsersDataTable userData;
    private System.Data.DataRow[] userAttr;

    public Test(){
        userAttr = userData.Select("'ID' = " + userID) ;
        Console.WriteLine(userAttr[0].Item["ID"]); //Where the ID is the name of a column
    }
}
```

The error is on the `userAttr[0].Item["ID"]` part, as the compiler says: "DataRow does not contain a definition for 'Item'

Comment: and you don't get an error on `System.Data.DataRow[] userAttr = new System.Data.DataRow();` ? by the way, you probably need `ItemArray`

Comment: .NET5.6? Back from the future?

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you referring to? .NET 5.6 doesn't exist...

Comment: Indeed I use the declaration: `private System.Data.DataRow[] userAttr;` on the class level, and give valu in the class constructor. Replace this in the question.

Comment: Please, when describing errors please provide the full error text (what I edited was generic), instead of just the CS code. The error often contains quite a bit of required information that we can't infer from the error number itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(userAttr[0]["ID"])
```

Comment: Have convinced, but could not answer MSDN reference problem: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: please learn english.... the item property is an indexer... you dont write x.item[5] just x[5]

Comment: But in this way how do I get,set these properties?

Comment: @HarmathBálint The underlying property name of an indexer method (to allow use of the indexing `[xx]` operator on a type) is `Item`. Much of MSDN to generated automatically, and assumes you know these things. For C# this is the only such case amongst properties.